# Is wpa_supplicant for android device specific or android version specific?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking, android-internet, android-wireless

I recently purchased sony xperia P, but it was not able to detect ad-hoc networks.
After some googling I came to know that android does not support ad-hoc network and I haven't modified the /system/bin/wpa_supplicant file so that it can also show ad-hoc networks. I found a lot of modified files on github but I dont know which one should I use. Is the file wpa_supplicant device specific or it is android version specific? 
My android version is 4.0.4 (Sony xperia P), can anyone give me the exact file I can use with my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Because the wpa_supplicant interact with the network card driver, and the driver is associated with the network card chips. And different network card support different range of of IEEE 802.11 (includes optional and mandatory standards  ) standard, so I guess the wpa_supplicant is specific to the network card chips.While it's possible that a version of wpa_supplicant supports several network driver and network card.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Modifying wpa_supplicant alone won't be enough to get ad-hoc working in Android (unless you plan to use it via command line and not Settings app). The Settings app and WLAN APIs filter out ad-hoc networks.

Also wpa_supplicant is not tied to particular hardware, but some changes that Android makes to wpa_supplicant are Android version dependant, based on what new feature gets added in new Android version.